# Trigger an event by the execution of another one

Tags: javascript

I want to integrate the last two loops into the first two loops in order to trigger the events from the last ones when the first ones fire.

```
function expand() {
var coll = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
for (x = 0; x < coll.length; x++) {
    coll[x].addEventListener("mouseenter", 
    function () {
        event.target.style.width = "480px";
    });
}
for (x = 0; x < coll.length; x++) {
    coll[x].addEventListener("mouseleave", 
    function () {
        event.target.style.width = null;
    });
}
var coll1 = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsing");
for (x = 0; x < coll1.length; x++) {
    coll1[x].addEventListener("mouseenter", 
    function () {
        event.target.style.maxHeight = "480px";
    });
}
for (x = 0; x < coll1.length; x++) {
    coll1[x].addEventListener("mouseleave", 
    function () {
        event.target.style.maxHeight = null;
    });
}
```

Maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) helps you more than me as I am a js beginner...

Comment: Do you mean you'd want, for example, `coll1[0]` to change `maxHeight` when `coll[0]` has a `mouseenter` event?

Comment: @Certainperfoormance yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your `for` loop, you have the index of the `.grid-item`s - simply select the item in the `.collapsing` `nodeList` at the same index, and then you can set its style as well:

```
const gridItems = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
const collapsings = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsing");
for (let i = 0; i < gridItems.length; i++) {
  gridItems[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
    gridItems[i].style.width = "480px";
    collapsings[i].style.maxHeight = "480px";
  });
  gridItems[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
    gridItems[i].style.width = null;
    collapsings[i].style.maxHeight = null;
  });
}
```

(note the use of `let i`, that's very important - best to avoid implicitly creating global variables, and use `const` or `let` instead of `var` to avoid unintuitive behavior from hoisting/function scope)

Another option to consider, rather than changing styles manually like this, would be to toggle classes on and off instead. Also, if these elements are all in a container, you might think about using event delegation, that way you only ever add *two* events overall, rather than two events for every element.

Comment: this works perfectly for the first tile in my grid but it doesnt work at all for the others and im still trying to figure out why the others are only expanding width but´not height

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] so that your problem can be reproduced

Comment: i cant do that because the project is very advanced at this point and the page is for example build entirely with scripts... its impossible at this point to cut a snippet..

Comment: Just Inspect the HTML in-browser once it's built and you can copy it, should be doable

Comment: can i somehow send you this privately? it got sensitive information

Comment: For questions to be on-topic, all the information necessary to reproduce the problem in the question needs to be posted *in the question itself* - please edit your question instead (otherwise it might get closed)

Comment: my reputation is not high enough to start a chat.. and i really cant post my entire code here..

Comment: Just post a small section of it, like 3 items, editing out any sensitive information

Answer (score -2):

Something like this?

```js
function expand() {

  var coll = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
  for (x = 0; x < coll.length; x++) {
    coll[x].addEventListener("mouseenter",
      function() {
        event.target.style.width = "480px";
        loop3(true);
      });
  }
  for (x = 0; x < coll.length; x++) {
    coll[x].addEventListener("mouseleave",
      function() {
        event.target.style.width = null;
        loop4(true);
      });
  }

  loop3(false);
  function loop3(auto_trigger) {
    var coll1 = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsing");

    for (x = 0; x < coll1.length; x++) {
      coll1[x].addEventListener("mouseenter",
        function() {
          event.target.style.maxHeight = "480px";
        });

      if (auto_trigger) coll1[x].style.maxHeight = "480px";
    }
  }

  loop4(false);

  function loop4(auto_trigger) {
    var coll1 = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsing");

    for (x = 0; x < coll1.length; x++) {
      coll1[x].addEventListener("mouseleave",
        function() {
          event.target.style.maxHeight = null;
        });

      if (auto_trigger) coll1[x].style.maxHeight = null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: try again, I edited. The collection of elements should be inside the function.

Comment: it still expands just the width by hovering only the grid-item. when i hover the collapsing item it works but this is not the goal

Comment: there. I think you mean it needs auto trigger of the maxHeight when width style is triggered?